# live wallpaper with images

Tags: android, bitmap, live, wallpaper, image

(sorry for my Englih is not so good... hope you will understand me)

My friend is a really good drawer. I would like to help him to be know as a good drawer by making him a live wallpaper animated with his drawings.

I would like him to draw few frames and use these frames to make a live wallpaper by displaying them one after the other.

I'm struggling so much to display one picture then wait a bit and display the next one. I'm quite sure that I can't succeed to do it because I don't use the right approach...

This is what I have done until now :

```
public class Cercle extends WallpaperService
{
public void onCreate() 
{
    super.onCreate();
}

public void onDestroy() 
{
    super.onDestroy();
}

public Engine onCreateEngine() 
{
    return new CercleEngine();
}

class CercleEngine extends Engine 
{
    public Bitmap image1, image2, image3;

    CercleEngine() 
    {       
        image1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img1);
        image2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img2);
        image3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img3); 
    }

    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) 
    {
        super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
    }

    public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xStep, float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels) 
    {
        drawFrame();
    }

    void drawFrame() 
    {
        final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();

        Canvas c = null;
        try 
        {
            c = holder.lockCanvas();
            if (c != null) 
            {              
                 c.drawBitmap(image1, 0, 0, null);
                 c.drawBitmap(image2, 0, 0, null);
                 c.drawBitmap(image3, 0, 0, null);                   
            }
        } finally 
        {
            if (c != null) holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }
    }
}
}
```

This code just display the pictures too quickly because I don't know how to wait between diplaying pictures...

Can anyone give me some tips or show me some example of another solution ?

Thanks so much !

**UPDATE :**

I got my problem resolved by adding a Runnable :

```
private final Runnable drawRunner = new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            drawFrame();
        }

    };
```

and then by adding :

```
    handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
        if (visible) 
        {
           handler.postDelayed(drawRunner, 1000); // delay 1 sec
        }
```

at the end of drawFrame().

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use this open source project to create nice live wallpaper for your friend

[link](http://code.google.com/p/android-wallpaper-slideshow/) it is read from phone gallery, you can edit it to read from folder in the project pr just use as it is.

or use this [link](http://code.google.com/p/photogallerylivewallpaper/) for other live wallpaper project

Comment: Thanks ahmed ! I got my problem resolved by looking at the source code at your links. Sorry I wanted to vote you up but It tells me that I need 15 reputation to be able to do it...

Answer (score -1):

@Pozinux... I'm a new programmer. I came across this code you have hear. I'm trying to use the code in my project. But I can't get it to work. When I install it to the emulator it doesn't move through its frames. It only shows the last frame. How did you set this up? Or get this to work? Hears how I set it up in my project.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

import android.graphics.Canvas;

import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService;

import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class WallpaperSer extends WallpaperService {

public void onCreate() 

{
    super.onCreate();
}

public void onDestroy() 
{
    super.onDestroy();
}

public Engine onCreateEngine() 
{
    return new WallpaperSerEngine();
}

class WallpaperSerEngine extends Engine 
{
    public Bitmap image1; 
    public Bitmap image2;
    public Bitmap image3;
    public Bitmap image4;
    public Bitmap image5;
    public Bitmap image6;
    public Bitmap image7;
    public Bitmap image8;
    public Bitmap image9;
    public Bitmap image10;
    public Bitmap image11;
    public Bitmap image12;
    public Bitmap image13;
    public Bitmap image14;
    public Bitmap image15;
    public Bitmap image16;
    public Bitmap image17;
    public Bitmap image18;
    public Bitmap image19;
    public Bitmap image20;

    WallpaperSerEngine() 
    {       
            image1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and1);
            image2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and2);       
            image3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and3); 
            image4 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and4);
            image5 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and5);
            image6 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and6);
            image7 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and7);
            image8 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and8);
            image9 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and9);
            image10 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and10);
            image11 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and11);
            image12 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and12);
            image13 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and13);
            image14 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and14);
            image15 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and15);
            image16 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and16);
            image17 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and17);
            image18 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and18);
            image19 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and19);
            image20 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.and20);
    }

    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) 
    {
        super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
    }

    public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xStep, float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels) 
    {
        drawFrame();

    }

    void drawFrame() 
    {
        final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();

        Canvas c = null;
        try 
        {
            c = holder.lockCanvas();
            if (c != null) 
            {              
                 c.drawBitmap(image1, 0, 0, null);
                 c.drawBitmap(image2, 0, 0, null);
                 c.drawBitmap(image3, 0, 0, null);
                 c.drawBitmap(image4, 0, 0, null);
                 c.drawBitmap(image5, 0, 0, null);
                 c.drawBitmap(image6, 0, 0, null);
                 c.drawBitmap(image7, 0, 0, null);
                 c.drawBitmap(image8, 0, 0, null);
                 c.drawBitmap(image9, 0, 0, null);
                 c.drawBitmap(image10, 0, 0, null);
                 c.drawBitmap(image11, 0, 0, null);
                 c.drawBitmap(image12, 0, 0, null);
                 c.drawBitmap(image13, 0, 0, null);
                 c.drawBitmap(image14, 0, 0, null);
                 c.drawBitmap(image15, 0, 0, null);
                 c.drawBitmap(image16, 0, 0, null);
                 c.drawBitmap(image17, 0, 0, null);
                 c.drawBitmap(image18, 0, 0, null);
                 c.drawBitmap(image19, 0, 0, null);
                 c.drawBitmap(image20, 0, 0, null);
            }
        } finally 
        {
            if (c != null) holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }
    }
}
}
```