# How to create Android Live 3D Wallpapers?

Tags: android, 3d, live, wallpaper

I was wondering how Android Live **3D** wallpapers are created? what software is used? and   how Developers make it interact with touch, swipe, etc... I hope someone help me how I can start ... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3d wallpapers are created in opengles. You can use libraries too . i am using Rajawali Library https://github.com/MasDennis/Rajawali . May be it will help u

Comment: Can Rajawali be used to show simple images and even videos and animations (animated GIF/WEBP), right on the live wallpaper ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper yes you can

Comment: Really? Is there a sample/tutorial of it? Or of any of this? I wonder how easy it is, and how well it will work. I've now tried their samples, but many don't seem to work at all (completely black or not responding to touches). The live wallpaper sample itself crashes for it... :(

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Question/Answer [live wallpaper with images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293985/live-wallpaper-with-images)
& for more about go to **TheNewBostonAndroid** for the Android video tutorials. Its very simple & easy to learn Android.

Comment: I've asked how the **3D** Live wallpapers is made not how to make a slideshow from some images. thanks

Comment: Boudi Alsayed, do you know OpenGL?

Comment: No Please tell me About OpenGL, I'm now searching for about it :)